# Excel macro to search for duplicate names in all rows

Tags: macros, microsoft-excel-2013

In an excel 2013 spreadsheet, Windows 10, how can I execute the following pseudo code in a macro, which I think will delete spreadsheet rows with duplicate first and last names:

```
from unknown last row n to row 1, step -1.  
If cell(An)=cell(An-1) and cell(Bn)=cell(Bn-1), then 
delete the entire row(n)
```

Answer (score 2):

This feature is built into Excel. You can go [here](http://www.computerforall.ca/microsoft-office/87-office-2013/excel-2013/206-how-to-remove-duplicate-values-in-microsoft-excel-2013) for a step-by-step guide.

The basics are...

1. Highlight the data you want to use to find the duplicates. (it sound like the first and last name columns)
2. Then go to the data tab at the top.
3. Then click remove duplicates
4. The next window shows you your selected rows. Click OK to confirm.
5. The next window shows you stats on how many duplicates were deleted.